# How to use Big Query with Firebase Authenticated Users

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I have around 8.4 Million users information in the Firebase Authentication Section. I want to process that information to market my new product and retarget users.

For that, I need to export the emails and Facebook UIDs from that data.

I have used Firebase Admin SDK to get that information on the server. But it is not perfect since it can get maximum 1000 records per request and also, it is time-consuming.

I want to know whether there is a way to use Google Cloud Tools to explore the data stored in the Firebase Console quickly or not?

Is there any way in Firebase Console to export that information?

Comment: You could try the [CLI command](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#authexport) `firebase auth:export`

Comment: Looks very promising, I'll try this thing.

Comment: Even the CLI SDK will paginate the requests under the hood. This is unavoidable. How often do you need to run your data processing?

Comment: My whole purpose right now is to add that emails to the mailchimp list and use the IDs to run the Facebook Marketing Campaigns. But, Yes I might have xyz requirement later on. So, first I am saving those records in a database and later on, I'll want to add it to a system which makes it easy for querying the information and export it. For example, if I wan to export all users who have email IDs with them. Processing that many records will take time as well.